# Crippled main character

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book series back in the early 90’s where the main character came from a tribe or something of renowned sword fighters. I think he ends up being the last. The big thing I remember is he ends up crippled. Can’t use his legs. He ends up fighting from horseback. I seem to recall it being a trilogy but honestly I may have been just the one book. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're off to a good start, but we could use some more details. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: Perhaps an odd question given the details, but: is this a fantasy series?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like the *[Renshai Trilogy](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/BPW/renshai-trilogy)* by Mickey Zucker Reichert.

The protagonist is the last of warrior people called the Renshai, and ends up being crippled. He then goes on to train some people in the Renshai fighting styles.

Details that match:

*in the early 90's*

This book, Last of the Renshai, was published in 1992.

*main character came from a tribe or something of renowned sword fighters*

The character, Rache, is the last survivor from a tribe of master swordsmen.

*The big thing I remember is he ends up crippled. Can’t use his legs. He ends up fighting from horse back*

Rache gets his spine broken and has to fight from the back of his horse Bein.

*I seem to recall it was being a trilogy*

It's part of the Renshai fantasy trilogy.

Comment: Can you provide any more details that suggest similarity? Any points from the book with match up with plot points mentioned?

Comment: @Edlothiad This answer pretty much confirms everything in the question.  It's also probably correct, based on my own memory.

Comment: Now it's nicely laid out and looks incredibly similar.

Comment: That’s it! Thank you thank you thank you! Been driving me nuts.